# What is a good way to test the onMeasure/onLayout/onDraw methods of a custom View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-testing

I just wrote a custom View class that, among other things, allows a developer to easily set borders (e.g. `setBorderWidth`, `setBorderColor`, `setBorderWidthLeft`, etc.). I did this by overriding `onMeasure`/`onDraw` and I want to test that the View properly draws these borders.

Ideally, I want something at a higher level than a unit test: basically I want to enforce that if I set borders, they are drawn as expected; if I don't set them they aren't drawn; if I change them, the new borders are drawn and the old ones are no longer visible. This allows me to know that my view is working at a high level.

Things I've considered:

1. Taking the view in isolation with Robolectric and calling onDraw manually with a mock Canvas (doesn't test invalidation though)
2. Making an Activity test case and somehow saving a screenshot of the Activity and analyzing it programmatically.

Neither of these seem great to me, but I'm leaning towards 2). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For testing `onDraw`, `onLayout` and `onMeasure`[screenshots-tests-for-android](https://facebook.github.io/screenshot-tests-for-android/) is considerable option.